# php unprintable strings

Tags: php, string, var-dump

My text strings behaves very strange when printing them. They all come from parsing a website with help of DOMDocuments. I have used `DOMNode::nodeValue` to get the parsed texts.

Most of my string is not printable with printf. Instead I get a warningmessage `"Warning: printf(): Too few arguments ".`
I've tried to use var_dump on the strings and they all contain string characters. Some are recognized by var_dump as strings, but they are not printable either. Should say that I'm rather guessing that var_dump recognizes them as strings since string(length of string) is printed before the dumped characters.
**Is there some sort of characters that could cause this behaviour that causes my strings to be interpreted as something else?**

Comment: do you print the characters to the console our try to view them in a webbrowser?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your string has something like `%d`, it expects a parameter to replace that with. For example: (taken from the [php docs](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php))

```
$format = 'There are %d monkeys in the %s';
printf($format, $num, $location);
```

Try printing it with `echo` instead.

Comment: Ok, now I am embarrassed. :) '%' signs in every string. Removing the '%' did the trick. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Use `printf` to format your string. Use `print` or `echo` if you just want to display a string as-is.